# fetching two rows at a time in loop

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to fetch two sets of data in a single query from MySQL using PHP.
Below method fetch one row at a time but I want to fetch two rows at a time.

```
$qblog = "SELECT * FROM `blogs` WHERE status='1' ";
$qblog1 = mysqli_query($con,$qblog);
while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($qblog1)){

<div><?php echo $data['blog_title'];?></div>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Please explain the purpose of this

Comment: well i am working on a page where blogs are displaying in such a way to show 2 records at a time.

Comment: Just add a `LIMIT 2` with your `SELECT` query and loop through the result set.

Comment: if i suppose having 20 records then how LIMIT 2 will work.

Comment: Rows are fetched one by one. There's no way to fetch them 2 by 2. Create some php code which will check that two rows are fetched.

Comment: *...blogs are displaying in such a way to show 2 records at a time.*, I believe you're trying to implement pagination with 2 records per page, isn't  it?

Comment: Well i have achieved this on the basis of conditions in loop, i suppose this is only and right way to do. thanks all of you for the time.

Comment: @Adas I've given an answer below. Hopefully this will give you a head start on how to achieve the desired outcome.

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with the given code? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

From your comment,

> ... i want to show blogs like here, [homehero.org/blog](https://www.homehero.org/blog) ,if you inspect element you will see 2 'blog-post' repeats in every 'rows'.

You have to use a counter variable to keep track of how many blog posts are being displayed on each row. So your code should be like this:

```
$qblog = "SELECT * FROM `blogs` WHERE status='1' ";
$qblog1 = mysqli_query($con,$qblog);

$counter = 1;
while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($qblog1)){ 
    if($counter % 3 == 0){
        // display the blogspots and style them
    }
    ++$counter;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there is a way to get two rows at a time other than using `LIMIT 2` in query. You can add some conditions to display two rows in a single iteration but in my point of view, you will need to add another loop inside `while` like this one:

```
    $qblog = "SELECT * FROM `blogs` WHERE status='1'";
    $qblog1 = mysqli_query($con, $qblog);
    $post_count = 0;

    while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($qblog1)):
        if($post_count === 2):
            echo "<p>--------------------</p>";
            foreach($data_temp as $data_tmp):
?>
                 <div><?php echo $data_tmp['blog_title'];?></div>
<?php
            endforeach;
            echo "<p>--------------------</p>";
            $post_count = 0;
            unset($data_temp);

        endif;

        $data_temp[] = $data;
        $post_count += 1;

    endwhile;
?>
```

I just had a look at https://www.homehero.org/blog which @Rajdeep Paul mentioned. It is about layout which means you can do it with CSS instead of going for conditions in PHP. Doing CSS way is a lot easier instead of making conditions in PHP.

Comment: Why is it that `$data_temp` is iterated before it is ever declared?

Answer (score 0):

This is not that hard if I understand correctly.

```php
$sql = "select * from blogs where status = '1'";
$qblog1 = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($qblog1)) {
   $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($qblog1);
}
```

because you are reading from the same result set the pointer is updated just fine.

Comment: Please share more details. How does this resolve the problem? As the OP wrote in the comment section: "well i am working on a page where blogs are displaying in such a way to show 2 records at a time" - how does your code help to achieve that?